# Which Google API to use to search for files?

Tags: xcode, pdf, ios5, google-api

I have a search bar which should show  me only the PDF files from Google when i start searching for something.Which API can i use for searching in google and how can i integrate that in my code.Are there  any tutorial available for it.

Comment: Please indicate where you're searching for PDF files (is it Google Docs?) and any other details you can.

Comment: i am searching it in google docs but it should made me  see only the pdf files which i can store locally in my app

Comment: Do you want Google Search API ? You want content search in file or Internet search for some PDF ?

Comment: i want to have internet serach in google fthat show me only  pdf but dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use the [Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/)

You'll [search by MIME type](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_files_by_type).

It'll look like this (but needs to be properly encoded):

```
GET https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/{http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind}application/pdf
```